# Antlr rule for Digit is not recognizing digits -

Tags: java, parsing, visual-studio-code, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to extend an existing grammar using Antlr4. In the .g4 file beside other rules the following is defined:

```
Digit
 :  ZeroDigit
     | NonZeroDigit
     ;

NonZeroDigit
            :  NonZeroOctDigit
                | '8'
                | '9'
                ;

NonZeroOctDigit
               :  '1'
                   | '2'
                   | '3'
                   | '4'
                   | '5'
                   | '6'
                   | '7'
                   ;

OctDigit
        :  ZeroDigit
            | NonZeroOctDigit
            ;

ZeroDigit
         :  '0' ;


SP
  :  ( WHITESPACE )+ ;
```

so on top of that (not only as a figure of speech) I added the following rules which are supposed to make use of these existing rules:

```
ttQL_Query
     : ttQL_TimeClause SP;

ttQL_TimeClause
     : FROM SP? ttQL_DateTime SP? TO SP? ttQL_DateTime; 

ttQL_DateTime
    : ttQL_Date ('T' ttQL_Time ttQL_Timezone)?;

ttQL_Timezone: 'Z' | ( '+' | '-' ) ttQL_Hour ':' ttQL_Minute; 

ttQL_Date: ttQL_Year '-' ttQL_Month '-' ttQL_Day;
ttQL_Time: ttQL_Hour (':' ttQL_Minute (':' ttQL_Second (ttQL_Millisecond)?)?)?;

ttQL_Year: Digit Digit Digit Digit;
ttQL_Month: Digit Digit;
ttQL_Day: Digit Digit;

ttQL_Hour: Digit Digit ;
ttQL_Minute: Digit Digit ;
ttQL_Second: Digit Digit ;
ttQL_Millisecond: '.' ( Digit )+;


FROM : ( 'F' | 'f' ) ( 'R' | 'r' ) ( 'O' | 'o' ) ( 'M' | 'm' ) ;
TO : ( 'T' | 't' ) ( 'O' | 'o' ) ;
```

This is supposed to be an extension of the open cypher query language (grammar can be found here: http://opencypher.org/resources/) but i dont get it to work. Its supposed to prefix a cypher query. The rule for that is simple:

```
ttQL
     : SP? ttQL_Query SP? oC_Cypher ;
```

So all the other existing rules as well as the one i stated in the beginning are used in oC_Cypher. I put all my rules on top of the antlr file and when trying to parse a query like the following:

```
FROM 2123-12-13T12:34:39Z TO 2123-12-13T14:34:39.2222Z MATCH (a)-[x]->(b) WHERE a.ping > 22" RETURN a.ping, b"
```

I get the following error messages by my parser:

```
line 1:5 mismatched input '2123' expecting Digit
line 1:10 mismatched input '12' expecting Digit
line 1:13 mismatched input '13' expecting Digit
line 1:29 mismatched input '2123' expecting Digit
line 1:34 mismatched input '12' expecting Digit
line 1:37 mismatched input '13' expecting Digit
```

The weird thing is, when i put my part of the grammar in a new .g4 file and create a parser only for the prefix part `FROM 2123-12-13T12:34:39Z TO 2123-12-13T14:34:39.2222Z` then everything works like a charm. I'm kind of lost here. I am using vscode, java, maven and the ANTLR4 Plugin with ANTLR version 4.9.2, mvn-compiler-plugin 3.10.1, java version 11

what could be the catch here ?

Comment: "beside other rules" I'm guessing those other rules include a lexer rule that matches multiple digits at once? And in the version of the grammar that works you presumably have no such rule.

Comment: Please add a complete grammar and input source that produces that error. The minimal grammar is not sufficient to help you.

Comment: If you are using https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/M21/Cypher.g4 , that grammar is really terrible: much that could go wrong, useless parentheses `( Digit )+`, completely out of control max-k, unoptimized expressions. The answer below is correct: lexer rules that are not directly referenced in a parser rule should be fragments in order to prevent garbage from happening, e.g., "fragment ZeroDigit". An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure. That's where I would start. Bart is correct: we need to see the *full* grammar and input string.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem by adding the rules you said to the original grammar at the top. The additional rules cannot work because there's a conflict in lexing `Digit` vs lexing `DecimalInteger`. Your extension cannot work as is because Antlr will always choose the rule with the longest string matching regardless of rule order. Lexing in Antlr is NOT parser aware. I would rename `Digit` to `digit`, and redefine the lexer/parser boundary from scratch. Make sure to print out the token stream and focus exclusively on getting the lexer working first, without even creating a parser.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful! I don't understand what you mean by "Anlr will always choose the rule with the longest string matching" tho. Could you explain that ? Is "longest string" related to the input string ? like when the input string is "2023xy" a rule which allows  2023xy is preferred over a rule which allows 2 (single digits) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the answers of kaby I could solve the problem for me. I don't know if this is the correct of handling this issue but for what I want to achieve it is sufficient. So please be careful with this solution if you have a similar problem and try to solve it.

As kaby noted the lexer seaches for the Token it can concatenate the most characters with, so i just made lexer rules out of the date and time so the numbers wouldnt get recognized as Integers. Here is my working solution:

```
ttQL_Query
     : ttQL_TimeClause SP?;

ttQL_TimeClause
     : FROM SP? DATETIME SP? TO SP? DATETIME; 

DATETIME:  DATE ('T' TIME TIMEZONE)?;

TIMEZONE: 'Z' | ( '+' | '-' ) Digit Digit ':' Digit Digit; 

DATE: Digit Digit Digit Digit '-' Digit Digit '-' Digit Digit;
TIME: Digit Digit (':' Digit Digit (':' Digit Digit ('.' (Digit)+ )?)?)?;


FROM : ( 'F' | 'f' ) ( 'R' | 'r' ) ( 'O' | 'o' ) ( 'M' | 'm' ) ;
TO : ( 'T' | 't' ) ( 'O' | 'o' ) ;
```

EDIT:

I discovered my solution contains another pitfall which I will add here. In case you are parsing integers or any other sequence of digits where it is possible that two digits are concatenated my TIME rule will be invoked and a TIME token will be created - at least if this rule is above other rules which could fit here. As someone who dealt the first time with lexers and parsers I found that it is most important to be careful about already existing Lexer rules. As kaby mentioned: take care about the Lexer first, print out the tokens of Example input for debugging. In my case a simple solution was to merge the DATE, TIME and TIMEZONE rules to make a more unique rule to not run into compatibility issues with the existing Lexer rules:

```
DATETIME:  (Digit Digit Digit Digit '-' Digit Digit '-' Digit Digit) ('T' (Digit Digit (':' Digit Digit (':' Digit Digit ('.' (Digit)+ )?)?)?) ('Z' | ( '+' | '-' ) Digit Digit ':' Digit Digit))?;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a `fragment` prefix to all lexer rules with the exception of `Digits` and SP.